# PHP Accessing specific content using Xpath attribute

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

For the below sample XML, I'm trying to `echo` each field in the `<other>` tag structure:

```
$theXML = new SimpleXMLElement($stringBody);

<Record>
 <PersonDetails>
    <StuffA>050656770</StuffA>
    <StuffB>Stuff B Content</StuffB>
    <StuffC>Stuff C Content</StuffC>            
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails>
    <StuffA>050656770</StuffA>
    <StuffB>Stuff B Content</StuffB>
    <StuffC>Stuff C Content</StuffC>   
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails>
    <StuffA>050656770</StuffA>
    <StuffB>Stuff B Content</StuffB>
    <StuffC>Stuff C Content</StuffC>   
    <OtherRelatedDetails>
       <OtherDetails>
          <Other>
             <core:AuthNum>3761626</core:AuthNum>                    
             <core:FromDate>2007-11-22</core:FromDate>
             <core:ToDate>9999-12-31</core:ToDate>
             <core:AuthType>A</core:AuthType>
             <core:Name>ABC</core:Name>
             <core:Num>3205355</core:Num>
          </Other>
          <Other>
             <core:AuthNum>4383908</core:AuthNum>
             <core:FromDate>2007-11-22</core:FromDate>
             <core:ToDate>9999-12-31</core:ToDate>
             <core:AuthType>B</core:AuthType>
             <core:Name>DEF</core:Name>
             <core:Num>3205355</core:Num>
          </Other>
          <Other>
             <core:AuthNum>8103583</core:AuthNum>
             <core:FromDate>2007-11-22</core:FromDate>
             <core:ToDate>9999-12-31</core:ToDate>
             <core:AuthType>C</core:AuthType>
             <core:Name>GHI</core:Name>
             <core:Num>3205355</core:Num>
          </Other>
       </OtherDetails>
    </OtherRelatedDetails>
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails>
    <StuffA>050656770</StuffA>
    <StuffB>Stuff B Content</StuffB>
    <StuffC>Stuff C Content</StuffC>                        
 </PersonDetails>
</Record>
```

This is a sample of the specific PHP I am trying to implement to `echo` each of the `<other>`

```
if (!empty($theXML->$record->$PersonDetails->OtherRelatedDetails->OtherDetails->Other[0])) {

foreach ($theXML->$record->$PersonDetails->OtherRelatedDetails->OtherDetails->Other as $OtherContent) {

    echo '<b>Authorisation Number: </b>' . $OtherContent->xpath("//Other[@core:AuthNum]") . '<br>';
    echo '<b>From Date: </b>' . $OtherContent->xpath("//Other[@core:FromDate]") . '<br>';
    echo '<b>To Date: </b>' . $OtherContent->xpath("//Other[@core:ToDate]") . '<br>';
    echo '<b>Authorisation Type: </b>' . $OtherContent->xpath("//Other[@core:AuthType]") . '<br>';
    echo '<b>Name: </b>' . $OtherContent->xpath("//Other[@core:Name]") . '<br>';
    echo '<b>Number: </b>' . $OtherContent->xpath("//Other[@core:Num]") . '<br>';
}}
```

Currently I am receiving:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\main\php\project.php on line 162

I have tried various iterations of the code (including imploding the array mentioned in the above error when imploding no values were came through) above but I'm having real trouble accessing the values correctly and getting this code back an into my UI. Any help will be much appreciated. (Please excuse any small XML or Code syntax problems I have obfuscated the values to make it generic for the purposes of this question..)

**EDIT 1**

I have tried the following:

```
foreach ($result->PersonDetails as $val) {
if (isset($val->OtherRelatedDetails->OtherDetails->Other)) {
    foreach ($val->OtherRelatedDetails->OtherDetails->Other as $value) {
        echo '<b>Authorisation Number: </b>' . $value[0] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Authorisation Type: </b>' . $value[3] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>From Date: </b>' . $value[1] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>To Date: </b>' . $value[2] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Name: </b>' . $value[4] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Number: </b>' . $value[5] . '<br>';
    }
}}
```

Comment: hope my code will help you out..

Comment: If your going to use XML and XPath, then you need to be careful with namespaces, you use 'core' in your document without defining it anywhere!  Also when using ->xpath, you will need to add the namespace into the context, something like `$OtherContent->registerXpathNamespace('core', 'core'); before you can successfully use `$OtherContent->xpath('core:AuthNum');`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out. Here we are using `simplexml_load_string` for parsing `XML`

Changes which can be done in current code of post

**Solution 1:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785376)

```
foreach ($result->PersonDetails as $val) {
if (isset($val->OtherRelatedDetails->OtherDetails->Other)) {
    foreach ($val->OtherRelatedDetails->OtherDetails->Other as $value) {
        $value=(array)$value;
        $value=array_values($value);
        echo '<b>Authorisation Number: </b>' . $value[0] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Authorisation Type: </b>' . $value[3] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>From Date: </b>' . $value[1] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>To Date: </b>' . $value[2] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Name: </b>' . $value[4] . '<br>';
        echo '<b>Number: </b>' . $value[5] . '<br>';
    }
}}
```

**Solution 2:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785275)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$result = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <Record>
 <PersonDetails>
    <StuffA>050656770</StuffA>
    <StuffB>Stuff B Content</StuffB>
    <StuffC>Stuff C Content</StuffC>            
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails>
    <StuffA>050656770</StuffA>
    <StuffB>Stuff B Content</StuffB>
    <StuffC>Stuff C Content</StuffC>   
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails>
    <StuffA>050656770</StuffA>
    <StuffB>Stuff B Content</StuffB>
    <StuffC>Stuff C Content</StuffC>   
    <OtherRelatedDetails>
       <OtherDetails>
          <Other>
             <core:AuthNum>3761626</core:AuthNum>                    
             <core:FromDate>2007-11-22</core:FromDate>
             <core:ToDate>9999-12-31</core:ToDate>
             <core:AuthType>A</core:AuthType>
             <core:Name>ABC</core:Name>
             <core:Num>3205355</core:Num>
          </Other>
          <Other>
             <core:AuthNum>4383908</core:AuthNum>
             <core:FromDate>2007-11-22</core:FromDate>
             <core:ToDate>9999-12-31</core:ToDate>
             <core:AuthType>B</core:AuthType>
             <core:Name>DEF</core:Name>
             <core:Num>3205355</core:Num>
          </Other>
          <Other>
             <core:AuthNum>8103583</core:AuthNum>
             <core:FromDate>2007-11-22</core:FromDate>
             <core:ToDate>9999-12-31</core:ToDate>
             <core:AuthType>C</core:AuthType>
             <core:Name>GHI</core:Name>
             <core:Num>3205355</core:Num>
          </Other>
       </OtherDetails>
    </OtherRelatedDetails>
 </PersonDetails>
 <PersonDetails>
    <StuffA>050656770</StuffA>
    <StuffB>Stuff B Content</StuffB>
    <StuffC>Stuff C Content</StuffC>                        
 </PersonDetails>
</Record>');
foreach($result->PersonDetails as $val)
{
    if(isset($val->OtherRelatedDetails->OtherDetails->Other))
    {
        foreach($val->OtherRelatedDetails->OtherDetails->Other as $value)
        {
            print_r(array_values((array)$value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @SahilGulati, thanks for your offer of assistance. I have a question, as you can see in my example where I echo my results back, that method allows me quite a bit of control, which I need, I have tried what you sent me as follows: **PLEASE SEE ABOVE IN QUESTION**

Comment: @BernardV can you tell me the error you are getting in your code, and which is line no `162`?

Comment: That would be on a the initial idea I proposed in the question (not related to your answer) the error was occurring when on the first line I tried to echo: `echo '<b>Authorisation Number: </b>' . $OtherContent->xpath("//Other[@core:AuthNum]") . '<br>';`

Comment: @BernardV why can't you go with this code.. My post's code is working fine you can check this..

Comment: @BernardV Do you want to echo every thing the way you are using in `<b>` is it what you want?

Comment: Yes as example shows below **Edit 1** section, is this possible using your method?

Comment: @BernardV can you check this https://eval.in/785376 Hope this will work fine as you want, according to **Edit 1**

Comment: Thanks very much @SahilGulati your answer makes perfect sense and but I simply am unable to get it working at the moment in my code, I keep getting `Undefined offset: 0 ` etc... I will keep trying and let you know if get this right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143171/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-bernardv).